# How to get the caller script name

Tags: python, file

I'm using Python 2.7.6 and I have two scripts:

outer.py

```
import sys
import os

print "Outer file launching..."
os.system('inner.py')
```

calling inner.py:

```
import sys
import os

print "[CALLER GOES HERE]"
```

I want the second script (inner.py) to print the name of the caller script (outer.py).
I can't pass to inner.py a parameter with the name of the first script because I have tons of called/caller scripts and I can't refactor all the code.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think is possible when you use `os.system`. You essentially go through os and invoke a new python session. You could set up some environment variable in `outer.py`, when calling `system` with it's name, and check for its presence in `inner.py`. I don't think there are any other workarounds.

Comment: If you're planning to make `inner.py` do different things depending on who calls it, that's going to be a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 9):

One idea is to use psutil.

```
#!env/bin/python
import psutil

me = psutil.Process()
parent = psutil.Process(me.ppid())
grandparent = psutil.Process(parent.ppid())
print grandparent.cmdline()
```

This is ofcourse dependant of how you start outer.py.
This solution is os independant.

Answer (score 5):

On linux you can get the process id and then the caller name like so.

p1.py

```
import os
os.system('python p2.py')
```

p2.py

```
import os

pid = os.getppid()
cmd = open('/proc/%d/cmdline' % (pid,)).read()
caller = ' '.join(cmd.split(' ')[1:])
print caller
```

running `python p1.py` will yield `p1.py`
I imagine you can do similar things in other OS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another, a slightly shorter version **for unix only**

```py
import os
parent = os.system('readlink -f /proc/%d/exe' % os.getppid())
```

Answer (score -1):

If applicable to your situation you could also simply pass an argument that lets inner.py differentiate:

```
import sys
import os

print "Outer file launching..."
os.system('inner.py launcher')
```

innter.py

```
import sys
import os

try:
    if sys.argv[0] == 'launcher':
        print 'outer.py called us'
except:
    pass
```