# how to tell if a script is running independently or called as subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two scripts, `A.py` and `B.py` let's call them. `A` is an independent script that can run on its own, but can also be run by calling it from `B`. `B` on the other hand needs `A` to complete. I need to include something in my `A` script so that a couple configurations can be altered depending on where it's being called from.

I'm calling `A` from `B` like this: `subprocess.call("A")`

What can I do to let `A` know that it was called from `B`?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114712/how-to-get-the-caller-script-name

Answer (score 2):

Use command line arguments:

```
subprocess.call(["A", "--called-from-B"])
```

Comment: Do you mean add an arg to `A`?