# How to get the caller script full path in Python

Tags: python

I have a caller script /home/x/a/a.py that uses module /home/x/b.py

Inside b.py, I want to know the full path of the caller script, i.e. /home/x/a/a.py. How can I get that?

I looked at [How to get the caller script name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114712/how-to-get-the-caller-script-name) but it only gave me the script name which is a.py

Comment: Do you want to get the "caller" when calling a method or when importing the module?

Comment: you can `pass` it as a variable when you call `b.py`, but other than that I don't think there is a practical way for `b.py` to know who called it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the path and name of the file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing) in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31867043/1467082) looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

A very simplified version of what happens (for the CPython interpreter):

Every time a method is called in Python a "frame" is added to the stack, after a method returns something the interpreter pops the last frame from the stack and continues execution of the previous frame with the return value injected in place of the method call

To get the previous frame you can call [`sys._getframe(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) (0 would get the current frame, 1 gets the previous frame). The inspect module provides a method [`getframeinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getframeinfo) that returns some useful information about the frame including the filename. This can be combined like so

```
import inspect
import sys

def foo():
    print('Called from', inspect.getframeinfo(sys._getframe(1)).filename)
```

Whenever `foo` is called it will print the filename of the calling method

Comment: This only gives me the filename of the caller, but I need the full path. Is it possible?

Comment: This will give you a relative path to your working directory. You should be able to combine those to get the absoulte path: `import os` `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)`