# How to get script/file name of particular line of code?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I've a generic file `log.py` in which i've imported python logging and used all functions in it.

now i need to format log such that

```
(current_script_name) [levelname] message
```

log.py

```
import logging
import inspect
import sys

class log(object):
    #file_name = sys.argv[0] #this will give b.py instead of a.py
    file_name = str(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())).split("/")[-1]
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="("+file_name+") [%(levelname)s] %(message)s")
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def info(msg):
        logging.info(msg)
    def error(msg):
        logging.error(msg)
    def warning(msg):
        logging.warning(msg)
    def debug(msg):
        logging.debug(msg)
```

Now, i've another file called `a.py`
where i have imported above file and used like

```
import log
def some():
    log.info("Hello this is information")
```

This will give an output below when i call `some()` in `b.py`

```
(log.py) [INFO] Hello this is information
```

but i expect below output because `log.info()` code is used in a.py

```
(a.py) [INFO] Hello this is information
```

> Note: I shouldn't pass any argument for `log.info(msg)` line in `a.py`

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to pass the file name of the executing script to the logger.

Inside a.py:

```
log.info("Hello this is information", executing_script=__file__)
```

(For more information about using the **file** variable: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-script-file-path/)

You would have to update all the function definitions in your log class if you do it this way though. Alternatively, you could include the executing script file name in the log class initializer:

```
class log(object):
  def __init__(self, executing_script):
    self.file_name = executing_script
  # ...
```

This way you can just reference `self.file_name` in your logging functions instead of having to pass a value to each one.

Comment: Hi @Rekamanon, this could be helpful but not much because i need to avoid passing arguments

Comment: Maybe this question is relevant to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114712/how-to-get-the-caller-script-name