# Identify parent script name from child script - Python

Tags: python, linux

I am using two scripts `parent.py` and `child.py` where the parent process executes the child script and waits for its completion. I would like to identify the name of parent script from child. This is to ensure security, that child is being called by the correct parent script.

I have tried solutions using os library present at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114712/how-to-get-the-caller-script-name). However, the solutions present in that question can be mocked using [setproctitle](https://pypi.org/project/setproctitle/) library. I would like to know if there is a way to do the same which cannot be mocked.

Thanks in advance.